# Setting email forwarding address

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In office 365 Admin Center you can set email forwarding address.

Is this possible to achieve via Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported by either API at this time. If scenario allows for you to leverage PowerShell cmdlets, you might want to look into the [Set-Mailbox cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123981(v=exchg.160).aspx) which can be used to set the forwarding address.