# Reading the email forwarding address

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

This question is very closely related to [Setting email forwarding address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861378/setting-email-forwarding-address), except that I want to use Microsoft Graph to get a list of all users that have set up e-mail forwarding and where. I don't need to change the address.

Is it possible to read the e-mail forwarding settings? I tried by getting the [mailboxSettings](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/mailboxsettings) object, but it doesn't seem to contain this information.