# Get and set email auto-forwarding address via microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am aware that this question was asked [a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861378/setting-email-forwarding-address).

Is it still not possible?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. How useless. And here we are now with the other API's being depreciated.